# Understanding the difference between SPARQL and semantic reasoning using Pellet

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantics, owl, ontology

I have a pizza ontology that defines different types of pizzas, ingredients and relations among them.
I just want to understand several basic things:

1. Is it correct that I should apply SPARQL if I want to obtain information without
   reasoning? E.g. which pizzas contain onion?
2. What is the difference between SPARQL and reasoning algorithms
   like Pellet? Which queries cannot be answered by SPARQL, while can
   be answered by Pellet? Some examples of queries (question-like) for the pizza ontology would be helpful.
3. As far as I understand to use SPARQL from Java with Jena, I
   should save my ontology in RDF/XML format. However, to use Pellet
   with Jena, which format do I need to select? Pellet uses OWL2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPARQL is a *query language*, that is, a language for formulating *questions* in. *Reasoning*, on the other hand, is the process of *deriving new information from existing data*. These are two different, complementary processes.

1. To retrieve information from your ontology you use SPARQL, yes. You can do this without reasoning, or in combination with a reasoner, too. If you have a reasoner active it means your queries can be simpler, and in some cases reasoners can derive information that is not really retrievable at all with *just* a query.
2. Reasoners like Pellet don't really answer queries, they just reason: they figure out what implicit information can be derived from the raw facts, and can do things like verifying that things are consistent (i.e. that there are no logical contradictions in your data). Pellet can figure out that that if you own a Toyota, which is of type Car, you own a Vehicle (because a Car is a type of Vehicle). Or it can figure out that if you define a pizza to have the ingredient "Parmesan", you have a pizza of type "Cheesy" (because it knows Parmesan is a type of Cheese). So you use a reasoner like Pellet to derive this kind of implicit information, and then you use a query language like SPARQL to actually ask: "Ok, give me an overview of all Cheesy pizzas that also have anchovies".
3. APIs like Jena are toolkits that treat RDF as an abstract model. Which syntax format you save your file in is immaterial, it can read almost any RDF syntax. As soon as you have it read in a Jena model you can execute the Pellet reasoner on it - it doesn't matter which syntax your original file was in. Details on how to do this can be found in the Jena documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. BTW, is the calculation of similarities between concepts of the ontology related to the reasoning process? E.g. Pizza A has 30% similarity with Pizza B, because both pizzas have ingredients "Parmesan" and "Onion".